# Importing transaction history from USAA into GnuCash

Tags: gnucash, usaa

I was able to export a `.csv` from my bank, USAA. However, when I attempted to import the CSV, I was met with errors, and kind of fumbled my way through it. However, after it was imported, none of the actual charges or deposits or balances were actually there.

Has anyone used GnuCash with USAA to either import an export or connect directly and pull account data?

I have seen these two links:

- https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Setting_up_OFXDirectConnect
- https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/OFX_Direct_Connect_Bank_Settings

And then this old forum post

- http://www.ofxhome.com/ofxforum/viewtopic.php?id=47536

However, none of it makes sense to me.